# How to call a script with a var interpreted as multiple arguments

Tags: bash

I have a var which is a string that contains several words like this:

```
my_var="foo bar baz"
```

I'd like to call another script and pass in `my_var`. I want this second script to see three arguments `foo` `bar` `baz` instead of a single argument `"foo bar baz"`

How is this done? Here's what currently have:

```
text_output=$( /bin/bash /the/second/script.sh ${my_var} )
```

This second script is expecting any number of arguments. And currently it says it is getting one argument. Could the syntax `${}` be the issue?

Comment: If you aren't quoting `${my_var}`, something in your script is miscounting the number of arguments it is receiving.

Comment: Either that, or IFS got changed and that's confusing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a plain parameter to store multiple arguments; this is what arrays are for.

```
declare -a my_arr    # optional
my_arr=( foo bar baz )
text_output=$( /bin/bash /the/second/script.sh "${my_arr[@]}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it unquoted so that shell will be able to expand it. Examples:

```
my_var="foo bar baz"

fn() { echo $#; }

fn "$my_var"
1

fn $my_var
3
```